# Web Push without Firebase Cloud registration?

Tags: firebase, service-worker, web-push

On [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications) they explain Web Push with Service Workers stating 
`Chrome currently uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) as its push service. FCM recently adopted the Web Push protocol.` and then explaining Firebase and so on...

Since the Service Worker gives me a **unique** endpoint and a pubkey, it seems to me that *technically* it should be possible to use that endpoint directly, without anything additionally - except if Google deliberally forces a registration.

I mean, just send a POST request to that endpoint, sending just the notification data encrypted/authenticated using the pubkey without any "VAPID".

Do I absolutely need a Firebase account or is it possible to access the endpoint directly (without additional registration) if I just want to send a notification to a single device?

Answer (score 4):

It's 2021 and all major browsers implement a push service and support **VAPID** now. You use a web push library (Javascript, Python, C#,..) of choice.

There is no need to register anywhere.

The technical mechanism in short is this:

1. You generate two VAPID keys once using the push library. One key is private and one is public.
2. The public key is used in the javascript as "application server key" when subscribing to the push service of the browser.
3. If the subscription is successful you receive a subscription object from the browser containing an endpoint and two additional keys.

   The endpoint is an address depending on the web browser / manufacturer and the service it is currently using. The endpoints look like (Oct 2021) e.g.

   Google Chrome  *h_tt_ps://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/cz9gl.....*, Microsoft Edge *h_tt_ps://wns2-par02p.notify.windows.com/w/?toke.....*, Mozilla Firefox *h_tt_ps://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABhaUA....*
4. If your server program has this information (endpoint and keys from subscription object) it can send a push message to the endpoint with the push library. The corresponding service in the web, hosted by the manufacturer sends this to the browser's service on the device.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [PushAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Push_API) which shall get used.
But it doesn't is supported by every Browser at the moment.

You can find nice examples in the [Service Worker Cookbook of Mozilla](https://serviceworke.rs/web-push.html)